# hpux: strange dsf thing

Tags: hp-ux

Running setboot

```
setboot
Primary bootpath : 0/1/1/0.0.0 (No dsf found)
HA Alternate bootpath : 0/0/2/0.0.0x0.0x0 (/dev/rdisk/disk3)
Alternate bootpath : 0/1/2/1 (LAN Interface)
```

My system boot fine,i don't understand why setboot doesn't see the dsf.
I tried

```
insf -e 0/1/1/0.0.0`
```

Nothing change.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That hardware path is not complete, probably the path to the disk is:

```
    0/1/1/0.0.0x0.0x0
```

Try this:

```
    ioscan -kfnN -H 0/1/1/0.0.0
```

You will get a line for the disk ending with "LUN path for diskX", like 0/1/1/0.0.0x0.0x0

Then, execute:

```
    # setboot -p 0/1/1/0.0.0x0.0x0
```

And your setboot output should be ok.

The system boots because that is the only disk it finds under that hardware path.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work,setboot -v still report no dsf found

Comment: Whoops,works fine the problem is setboot doesn't report the dsf if run as user,run as root report ok